Why does Hashem, Who is all-merciful, let children get cancer and suffer and die?
Even if there are reasons beyond human comprehension, the seemingly unjustifiable cruelty of letting/making children (and their families!) suffer makes Hashem “look bad” in some people’s eyes. It’s a challenge even for people who believe in Hashem. Is this not a Chillul Hashem?

Ah, and he/she lands with the biggest question of them all. If sins from a prior gilgul, parents sins, enabling others to become better are unsatisfying to you then you can always go with that man polluted the planet and created the carcinogens, not God. Or that if only the bad suffered free will would disappear. Iyov doesn't seem to give an answer to it, it's the biggie that believers in an omnipotent, omniscient and benevolent God need to contend with . .

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Apparently God doesn't think so. However, you're welcome to make that argument next time you pray, similar to Moshe's after the Eigel debacle.
